# TypeScript Discriminated Unions problem with setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

Lets say I have a type that looks as follows:

```
export type IEntity = ({
    entity: IReport
    setEntity: (report: IReport) => void
} | {
    entity: ITest
    setEntity: (test: ITest) => void
});
```

Both entity and setEntity are functions from a zustand store.

My component looks like this:

```
type IProps = {
    values: IValues
    meta: IMeta
} & IEntity;

export const CreateField = (props : IProps) => {
  ...
```

So when I try to call setEntity inside this component, I get the following error:

Argument of type  IReport | ITest  is not assignable to parameter of type  IReport & ITest

How can I fix this? How do I have to write the correct type definition??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXyb9N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much. An answer with an explanation would be so nice! I'll accept it for sure! :D Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which considers moving to generics. First, we will need some map type that will hold the part of the props that is different:

```
type TypeMap = {
  report: IReport;
  test: ITest;
};
```

Now, let's generate the discriminated union, but by using the generics:

```
type IProps<T extends keyof TypeMap> = {
  values: "IValues";
  meta: "IMeta";
} & {
  [K in T]: {
    entity: TypeMap[K];
    setEntity: (entity: TypeMap[K]) => void;
  };
}[T];
```

We are accepting a generic argument that is constrained to be a key of `TypeMap` and by using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we create an object in the shape of `type: {entity, setEntity}`. Then by using the generic argument, we get the desired attribute.

Last, but not least is to turn our component into a generic component:

```
export const CreateField = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(props: IProps<T>) => {
  props.setEntity(props.entity); // no error
};
```

If you hover over `props.setEntity` you will see that it accepts an argument of type `TypeMap[T]` and the `props.entity` has exactly that type. In short, we restrict the compiler from narrowing to the exact type which does the trick.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgShMB7ATsKBeKBvAUFKFRVYALigGdgUBLAOwHMBuXAXxd1ElgBUIrMOfFGD8ylavWZsOXaD3AQAsgEMwgvASLI05eMTQsCoqnr5UW7XNbmwACiiRgKAHh5QIAD1F0AJhSgAawgQJAAzKAVIVTAAPg1hADcVABsAV35yACIYADVUjIosoygAWwhgFWyYJQqVYrYoADIhAgBtAGkoekiAXXJNAg86YBpQcijlNU7ekoIKCoBREbGQcgAKCBXxyMUYmYBKTHjEpBpfEqtWNp5Z6y8ddABjJDoBAGEiFVEAMRoIFK+QRuDzeLb+IIhcK7aJqWLrMCOZx6BxOVw8WJHDDxQaItEAOgWwGWo1ACKRFHxW1JIAOTCgAHoGVA6EgPChHCgZLggA)